# Salt and Hash passwords in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, security

Are there any libraries available for Java which makes creating and checking salted hashed passwords simply by calling a method?

Comment: I have used mindrots bcrypt implementation: http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/ - but this question is off-topic I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).
Shiro also has tag library for JSP.
[Tutorial For Shiro with JSP](http://balusc.blogspot.com.tr/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html)

Here is a code sample that creates salted hash.

```
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.RandomNumberGenerator;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.SecureRandomNumberGenerator;
...

//We'll use a Random Number Generator to generate salts.  This
//is much more secure than using a username as a salt or not
//having a salt at all.  Shiro makes this easy.
//
//Note that a normal app would reference an attribute rather
//than create a new RNG every time:
RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
Object salt = rng.nextBytes();

//Now hash the plain-text password with the random salt and multiple
//iterations and then Base64-encode the value (requires less space than Hex):
String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(plainTextPassword, salt, 1024).toBase64();

User user = new User(username, hashedPasswordBase64);
//save the salt with the new account.  The HashedCredentialsMatcher
//will need it later when handling login attempts:
user.setPasswordSalt(salt);
userDAO.create(user);
```